# Command works in terminal, but not with Runtime.exec

Tags: java, linux, shell, command-line

I'm trying to run some commands from a Java application using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)`. However, certain commands that work from a command line tool like Terminal fail when executed like this.

Example:

```
private static final String COMMAND = "cp -n /home/me/Downloads/a.png /home/me/Downloads/b.png";
private static final String COMMAND_2 = "cp -n /home/me/Downloads/a.png /home/me/Downloads/b.png && cp -n /home/me/Downloads/a.png /home/me/Downloads/b.png";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int result = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(COMMAND).waitFor();
    System.out.println(result); // prints 0
    int result2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(COMMAND_2).waitFor();
    System.out.println(result2); // prints 1
}
```

Note that `COMMAND_2` does the same as `COMMAND` twice, separated by `&&`. Why does one succeed, but the other fail? Both work just fine in Terminal.

I'm using Oracle-Java 1.7.0 on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.

Comment: You might need to give the fully-qualified path the `cp`, e.g. `/bin/cp`.

Comment: try to execute with replacing && to ';'

Comment: 1. use a `ProcessBuilder`; 2. a `Process` _is not_ a shell interpreter!

Comment: @MiteshParmar No difference. @fge What exactly is it, i.e. what is used to interpret that command? I found out that it works when explicitly running `bash` with my command as argument.

Comment: Well, `bash` is an example of a shell interpreter; and `bash` is itself a process. But there is no reason to use `bash` at all for a process, except if you execute a shell script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the most common mistake of all times when it comes to a `Process`.

**A process is not a shell interpreter**. As such, any special shell "keywords" will not be interpreted.

If you try and exec `cmd1 && cmd2`, what happens is that the arguments of the process are literally `cmd1`, `&&`, `cmd2`. Don't do that.

What is more, don't use `Runtime.exec()`. Use a `ProcessBuilder` instead. Sample code:

```
final Process p = new ProcessBuilder("cmd1", "arg1", "arg2").start();
final int retval = p.waitFor();
```

See the javadoc for `ProcessBuilder`, it has a lot of niceties.

Oh, and if you use Java 7, don't even bother using external commands. Java 7 has `Files.copy()`.

And also, `man execve`.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Someone else started using commands, and I think the original reason were `tar` operations, which can be done quick and dirty that way. But yeah, it feels hacky to me, too.

Answer (score -1):

The command and each of it's arguments must be separate items in a String array. Eg:

```
private static final String[] COMMAND = { "cp", "-n", "/home/me/Downloads/a.png", "/home/me/Downloads/b.png" };

....

int result = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(COMMAND).waitFor();
```

Comment: That's not the problem here.